# create array at startup in extern variable xcode

Tags: ios, nsarray

Hi I am looking for a way to perform a database fetch at start up and keep those items in an array.
My solution, although crude was to create an extern variable in viewDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions

I used

```
appdelegate.h
extern NSArray *listArray;
```

then

```
appdelegate.m 
NSArray *listArray;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
listArray = [self createGlobalArray];
//other startup code, etc...
```

The problem is that when I go to any view controller and for example in viewdidload I say

```
VC1.m

-(void)viewDidLoad{
myVCArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:listArray];

}
```

I get two errors: Apple Match-O linker error (directory not found...)

How do i fix this error?
Also is there a better way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually linker errors are because things aren't being properly included in your build settings somewhere.  I'd make sure that Build Phases > Compile Sources as well as Build Phases > Linked Libraries contain all the files your project needs.

Comment: ok, it's strange because this is the only time it has happened in the app, and only happens when I make a call to use this variable. I'm not convinced that's fully it

Comment: A linker error has to happen at build time.  It's potentially a problem with the file containing this variable.  Also make sure that listArray is only ever being instanciated once.